# Why the pixels of a jpeg image are different in different image library?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I read a jpeg image and export the rgb values of pixels in three ways: matlab, PIL and UIImage in iOS. The pixels are not the same completely. Most of pixels are the same, but a part of pixels are different slightly(the max diff is about 11 while the range of RGB is 0~255).

What is the underlying reason? Is it about the decompress algorithm of jpeg?

Thanks in advance.